# AlertDialog return

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a generic tagger class I created that can be used throughout my application. So activity1 can be tagged as type1, type2, etc. using an AlertDialog populated with valid tag types for the activity. The tags are being stored to the database correctly, however now I want to update a TextView in the activity with the selected value.

I tried using an AsyncTask but it seems I cannot background the AlertDialog (which makes sense). I got similar results trying the View.post(Runnable) method.

Given that the AlertDialog is happening in an external class, is there anyway for me to know that it has closed in my main activity and then update the TextView?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like to know when the dialog is dismissed.  There is a callback in place for that purpose, OnDismissListener.  Have your activity implement that interface and register itself for the callback.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)

Answer (score 0):

Depends where your AlertDialog initialization code is.  If you're launching the AlertDialog from the Activity that needs to be updated, you can just call a method of the Activity in the dialog's OnClickListener callback.  If the dialog is being initialized elsewhere in the application and has no knowledge of which Activity will be the current one, you can use the LocalBroadcastManager to send a broadcast message from the AlertDialog's callback and register/unregister a BroadcastReceiver in each Activity that would need to be updated if it is the currently active one.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `onClick()` listener for positive button:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
     {
       TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
       if (text != null)
       {
         text.setText("Your Text");
       }
     })
  .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).create().show();
```